# Поместить строку в буфер ввода консоли cmd.exe

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Необходимо открыть терминал cmd.exe и в его буфер ввода поместить строку (название скрипта). Возможно ли обойти работу с [ctypes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-input-buffer)? Сейчас я вижу только этот весьма затруднительный вариант решения. То есть, я ищу более простое решение.

Comment: pyautogui не подходит ?

Comment: @Интик, да, но с ним не будет надежности. Его использование будет значить то, что пользователь должен будет оставить управление на некоторое время, что мне бы не хотелось.

Comment: это ведь на винде ? может обычный bat'ник сделать ?

Answer (score 3):

в модуле `os` есть функция `system`которая принимает строку и выполняет её как комманду командной строки он же `cmd`

```
import os

os.system('ipconfig') #ipconfig как пример команды
```

`os.system()` принимает точно такиеже команды как и в `cmd` но только в виде строки

```
os.system('dir /s | find "..." ')
```